# C++ With Initializer List a thing, when to use normal constructor?

Tags: c++

I just started getting back into C++ here recently and learned about Initializer Lists. It seems to be the standard way to initialize members. That being said I have 2 questions regarding it:

1. Is there ever a reason to NOT use this method when setting private member variables (and just using the old fashioned setting it in the constructor).
2. What exact benefit do we get from this? I've been told "speed" but not exactly why?

edit: For reference Im more specifically speaking of using them for class initialization.

Comment: Not too familiar with initializer lists (my old compiler that I use doesn't support them, so I haven't played with them enough), but I think they allow you to things like `MyClas c = {1,2,3,4,5);`. Again, not 100% sure though.

Comment: @Chipster: I think OP means the ctor-initialization-list, which has been supported for a very long time.

Comment: @BenVoigt So has `std::initializer_list`. I'm just still on visual studio 2010, and it doesn't fully support C++11. Anyway, my mistake. I wasn't thinking about it the other way. Maybe the OP should clarify which one they mean, since there are two meanings for "initializer_list".

Comment: @Chipster: No, the term "initializer list" has only one meaning.  But from the contrast vs "setting" in the constructor body, I'm led to believe that's not what OP means to ask about.  And when I say *a very long time* I don't mean a mere 8 or 9 years, I mean since before C++ had a standard (pre-C++98).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Initialization list is about calling ctor of member variables. If you assign, you are altering the value of instance by using assign function. Obviously, these two are different functions.

There are a few cases that you cannot assign value to member variable in the ctor.

- When the member variable is const.
- When the member variable is an instance of class without default
  ctor.
- When the member variable is a reference (same reason as above)
- Initializing base class

When you create an instance without init-list, the member variable runs its ctor and then assign if you give value to it. It's a subtle difference but it might incur some penalty as the ctor runs first, and assign runs 2nd - which is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Very good response.  And to answer the OP's question: use the ctor initialization list for those members you *cannot* initialize in the constructor itself.

Comment: @paulsm4: That would be *all* members.  The constructor body cannot initialize any members at all.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - OK: wrong verb.  Let me rephrase: Use the ctor initialization list for those members you cannot "set" in the constructor itself.  Use ctor initialization where necessary - but prefer to set members in the constructor whenever practical. C++ is one of the few languages perverse enough to make a distinction between "set" and "initialiize" :(

Answer (score 4):

You should know that "setting (member data) in the constructor (body)" is assignment to an already-initialized object.  That cannot supply constructor arguments.  `const` members and references cannot be assigned.

The ctor-initializer-list (and since C++11, brace-or-equal-initializers specified at the member point of declaration) do true initialization, and should be preferred.

The constructor body can still have some uses... doing things with side effects, or looping... but even these can be accomplished by invoking a helper function from inside one of the ctor-initializer-list expressions.

Also, member initialization is the only way for their setup to fail in a way that doesn't lead to later destruction.  An exception in a constructor body will abort creation of the parent object... but destructors still need to run for all subobjects, so any setup to put them in a known, destructable state has to already be complete.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor initializer list is a very useful tool. I would reject your code in code review if you wouldn't be using it.

C++ has 2 ways of initializing members. Whenever you declare your member, you can give it a default value:

```
class C {
    int i = 42;
public:
    C(int j);
    C() = default;
};
```

This is a very useful technique to initialize simple members on a good default value.

Than, you have the initializer list:

```
C(int j) : i{j} {}
```

In this list, you can override the initialization. All members not mentioned get the initialization from the definition. Note that classes with default constructors don't require explicit initialization.

The initializer list can use the arguments of the constructor. However by initializing the members on definition, it is easier to spot uninitialized members.

So when not to use the initializer list for initialization? Never, as assignment in the constructor body is assignment, not initialization.

You never really need the body to assign members, however, if you don't have the `-Wreorder` warning active, it might make sense to assign a member that depends on another.

Comment: And why did you actually initialize i using brace initialization? Though it has all features of an aggregate type for which brace initialization has been designed, it's an integral type. Don't get me wrong please, I'm not blaming, I just see brace initialization is being applied by many developers everywhere even if there are no clear indications for it. Is it an abuse, a matter of coding fashion or there are any real advantages of using it for initializing integral variables?

Comment: I should check the details again, however, I thought this disallows narrowing conversions